# c# EOT End of transmission character in string

Tags: c#, encoding, ascii, eot

If I have a byte array and it ends with EOT character  when I use:

```
string str = ASCII.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myByteArray);
```

If I look the content of string str under visual studio is it normal to see it ends with like this "...\u0004"?

It seems like \u0004 is a Unicode code.

Comment: 0x4 is EOT in Unicode & ASCII.  Whether thats correct depends on what you are doing, if you see an EOT then either it was deliberately added by wherever myByteArray came from or myByteArray uses a non ASCII encoding with multi-byte characters the last of which happens to be 0x4.

Comment: I need to send a byte array to the device over serial port and it must end with EOT. I'm creating myByteArray like this : static byte EOT = 4; ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(someotherString + (char)EOT); Is this correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah what you are doing is fine.

Recently I was solving a problem, in which data was encoded and while decoding the data, there were 3 EOT's at the end of the string.

I guess you are fine with using one EOT.